# using wkhtmltopdf convert a file to pdf is smaller in size than the real file

Tags: php, python, wkhtmltopdf

When I convert a file with 158 pixel to pdf file, I just got a pdf file with 121 pixel in 100% zoom.

wkhtmltopdf --dpi 100 c:\1.svg c:\2.pdf

when I change the DPI, I find't it doesn't work. --dpi 100 is the same as --dpi 1000.

wkhtmltopdf version is 0.11, test under windows and linux.

Comment: Could you post your source file? I want to test this knowing even though I'm guessing that getting pixel-perfect might be difficult as PDFs don't really work with pixels, do they?

Comment: I am not sure what system you are testing on but I am having the same issue, found this in the docs: -d, --dpi <dpi> Change the dpi explicitly (this has no effect on X11 based systems)

Answer (score 4):

Try with the `--disable-smart-shrinking` option